# Signal TabHost to reload view

Tags: android, view, reload

I have a view that's contained inside a TabHost's FrameLayout. How can I programmatically tell the TabHost to reload the same view that's requesting it ? Something like "reset" in html.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can access your `Tab` by using [LocalActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/LocalActivityManager.html) and and you can access this via `getLocalActivityManager()`.

In `LocalActivityManager` there are two methods available namely `destroyActivity()` and `startActivity()`..

```
LocalActivityManager localActivityManager = getLocalActivityManager();
localActivityManager .destroyActivity("tabid", true);
localActivityManager .startActivity("tabid", new Intent(this, YourTab.class));
```

Here `tabid` is the `String` which has been used in `TabHost.newTabSpec(tabid)).`

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I see getLocalActivityManager belongs to an ActivityGroup though. Is there a way to use it from the view itself?

Comment: To achieve this  extend your `Activity` to be derived from `ActivityGroup`.